# How to correctly implement a TAP method?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I want to provide a task-based asynchronous pattern-style method. When awaiting the method, I could not find any difference between these two ways of providing the method:

```
// GetStats is a delegate for a void method in this example
public Task GetStatsAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(GetStats);
}

public async Task GetStatsAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(GetStats);
}

// Usage:
await GetStatsAsync();
// Difference?
```

The upper method seems to have less overhead than the lower one. When looking at the MSDN blogs, I noticed that they seem to use the lower method. (For example in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx))

Why? What exactly is the difference? They both seem to work.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and replace `TaskEx` with `Task`, as that's the way it is commonly known now.

Comment: @Varvara Kalinina Done

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are both logically the same, but the second one has more overhead and is not recommended for that reason.

You may find my [`async` intro helpful](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), as well as the [task based asynchronous pattern document](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957).

For more information on the overhead of `async`, I recommend the [Zen of Async by Stephen Toub](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T).

You probably also want to read ["Should I Expose Asynchronous Wrappers for Synchronous Methods?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) In short, the answer is "no."

Comment: The first one isn't recommended either! Let the caller choose if he wants to run on the thread pool or not. Just putting a Task.Run in there doesn't make the algorithm magically non-blocking.

Comment: They do use the Run method in the first sample for progress reporting (`int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(() =>`).

Comment: You're correct. The MSDN sample code is not as efficient as it could be.

Comment: For those curious about the last link (which is broken by now): https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/

Comment: @Beltway: Thanks! I updated the post. A couple years ago MS changed *all* their blog links and didn't put in forwarding for some reason...

Answer (score 4):

I was under the impression that the proper way of implementing a TAP pattern would be the following:

```
  public Task<IResult> GetLongWindedTaskResult(){
          var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IResult>();
            try
            {
               tcs.SetResult(ResultOFSomeFunction());
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                tcs.SetException(exp);
            }
            return tcs.Task;
}
```

This way ensures that you correctly get an exception if thrown and it would make it easier to implement a cancel method if needed.